# Unresolved dependencies error in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

So i just started working with IntelliJ and created my first project, but i get this error in the `Messages make`

[image]

and this in the `Event log`

[image]

this is the content of my my `build.gradle` file

[image]

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Your one dependency (of the form *groupId:artifactId:version*) is not quite right. You have the version listed as just `+`. Instead, it needs to be `18.0.+`, which specifies a release version of 18.0.0 or greater.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) for details.

Comment: Your post didn't mention it, so I assumed you downloaded the support libraries as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download). Did you?

Comment: Yes i downloaded all the support libraries.`Android Support Libraries`, `Android Support Repository` etc all from `extras` in the `SDK Manager`

Comment: The lack of Android Support Repository is what's causing this error. Is there any chance you have more than one SDK installed and you don't have the repository installed in the one you're using? If you click the SDK Manager button from the toolbar it should work with the same one it's using to compile, but you could double-check all the paths.